# spring boot logging some loggers at DEBUG even though root logger is at INFO

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, logback

We have a simple spring boot 3.1 app.

The application.properties has:

```
logging.level.root=INFO
```

Still, the following loggers are being logged at DEBUG level:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor
com.events.debeziumconnectorservice.controllers.HealthCheckController
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping
org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping
```

Any ideas?

The dependency tree looks like:

```
[INFO] --- dependency:3.5.0:tree (default-cli) @ events-cdc-connector ---
[INFO] com.mycompany.myproject.events:events-cdc-connector:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.20.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.20.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:2.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.33:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.15.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.15.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.15.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.15.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:10.1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:10.1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:10.1.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:6.0.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:6.0.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:6.0.9:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:6.0.9:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:6.0.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:jar:3.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:6.0.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:6.0.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:6.0.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:3.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.github.luben:zstd-jni:jar:1.5.2-1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.lz4:lz4-java:jar:1.8.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.1.8.4:runtime
[INFO] |  +- io.micrometer:micrometer-observation:jar:1.11.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-commons:jar:1.11.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:runtime
[INFO] +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.24:provided
[INFO] +- com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:jar:8.0.32:compile
[INFO] +- org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:jar:4.8:compile
[INFO] +- io.debezium:debezium-api:jar:2.1.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:2.0.7:compile
[INFO] +- io.debezium:debezium-embedded:jar:2.1.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.debezium:debezium-core:jar:2.1.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.15.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.kafka:connect-api:jar:3.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.1.1:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.kafka:connect-runtime:jar:3.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.kafka:connect-transforms:jar:3.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-tools:jar:3.4.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-server-common:jar:3.4.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- com.yammer.metrics:metrics-core:jar:2.2.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- net.sourceforge.argparse4j:argparse4j:jar:0.7.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- ch.qos.reload4j:reload4j:jar:1.2.19:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.bitbucket.b_c:jose4j:jar:0.7.9:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.15.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:2.15.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:jar:2.15.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.15.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:jar:3.1.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:jar:3.1.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- jakarta.inject:jakarta.inject-api:jar:2.0.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:3.1.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.3:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:3.1.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:3.1.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- jakarta.ws.rs:jakarta.ws.rs-api:jar:3.1.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.inject:jersey-hk2:jar:3.1.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:3.0.3:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:jar:3.0.3:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:3.0.3:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:3.0.3:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.29.0-GA:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:11.0.15:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.toolchain:jetty-jakarta-servlet-api:jar:5.0.2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:11.0.15:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:11.0.15:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:11.0.15:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:11.0.15:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:jar:11.0.15:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:11.0.15:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:jar:11.0.15:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-alpn-client:jar:11.0.15:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.reflections:reflections:jar:0.9.12:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:3.8.4:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.3.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.12.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations:jar:2.2.0:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.kafka:connect-json:jar:3.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.kafka:connect-file:jar:3.4.0:compile
[INFO] +- io.debezium:debezium-connector-mysql:jar:2.1.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.debezium:debezium-storage-kafka:jar:2.1.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.debezium:debezium-storage-file:jar:2.1.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.debezium:debezium-ddl-parser:jar:2.1.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.zendesk:mysql-binlog-connector-java:jar:0.27.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:8.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.5.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:3.1.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:3.1.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:3.1.0:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.8.0:test
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:4.0.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:2.1.2:runtime
[INFO] |  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.4.10:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:2.4.9:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:9.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.24.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.14.4:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.9.3:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.9.3:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.9.3:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.9.3:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.9.3:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.9.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:5.3.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.14.4:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:5.3.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:6.0.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:6.0.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:6.0.9:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.9.1:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:jar:1.11.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.12:runtime
[INFO] |     \- org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:jar:2.0.3:runtime
[INFO] +- io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-datadog:jar:1.11.0:compile
[INFO] \- com.datadoghq:java-dogstatsd-client:jar:4.2.0:compile
[INFO]    \- com.github.jnr:jnr-unixsocket:jar:0.36:compile
[INFO]       +- com.github.jnr:jnr-ffi:jar:2.1.16:compile
[INFO]       |  +- com.github.jnr:jffi:jar:1.2.23:compile
[INFO]       |  +- com.github.jnr:jffi:jar:native:1.2.23:runtime
[INFO]       |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:jar:7.1:compile
[INFO]       |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:jar:7.1:compile
[INFO]       |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:7.1:compile
[INFO]       |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-util:jar:7.1:compile
[INFO]       |  +- com.github.jnr:jnr-a64asm:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO]       |  \- com.github.jnr:jnr-x86asm:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO]       +- com.github.jnr:jnr-constants:jar:0.9.17:compile
[INFO]       +- com.github.jnr:jnr-enxio:jar:0.30:compile
[INFO]       \- com.github.jnr:jnr-posix:jar:3.0.61:compile
```